# Center a button (align horizontally) in HTML

Tags: html

I'm trying to center (align horizontally) a button on my email template.  Here is my current code:

```html
<p class="product-link" style="text-align:left; width:60%; display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">
    <span>
        <a style="color:#000000; background:#F4D079; padding:10px 15px; display:inline-block; margin-bottom:10px; text-decoration:none; border-radius:5px; font-size:14px;" href="https://www.amazon.com/review/review-your-purchases/ref=?_encoding=UTF8&amp;asins=[[PRODUCT_ASIN]]">Share your opinion</a>
    </span>
    <br>
</p>
```

I know this is an amateur question and I apologize, I've tried a million things and haven't gotten anything to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed unnecessary styles (width:60%; display:inline-block;),and added style to center the button(text-align: center;).

```html
<p class="product-link" style="text-align: center;vertical-align:middle;">
  <span><a style="color:#000000; background:#F4D079; padding:10px 15px; display:inline-block; margin-bottom:10px; text-decoration:none; border-radius:5px; font-size:14px;" href="https://www.amazon.com/review/review-your-purchases/ref=?_encoding=UTF8&amp;asins=[[PRODUCT_ASIN]]">Share your opinion</a></span><br>
<script type="text/javascript">
    
</script>

</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the parent element to display block and the button to margin-left and margin-right auto :)